# onReadyToSubscribe() is never getting called on native Android

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

After login using adapter based authentication, I have two buttons on my Task Activity  1) Subscribe 2) Un-Subscribe.

Login using adapter based authentication is working fine.

However, `onReadyToSubscribe()` is never called and also on the MobileFirst Operations Console I don't see any registered device. I also tried creating a challenge handler but still no luck.

TaskActivity

```
private void IBMPushNotificationRegisterEvent(){

    client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
    push = client.getPush();

    PushListener listener = new PushListener(PushListener.MODE_CONNECT,this);

    push.setOnReadyToSubscribeListener(listener);
    client.connect(listener);
}



private void SubscribeNotification(){
    client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
    client.getPush().subscribe("myAndroid",new WLPushOptions(), new PushListener(PushListener.MODE_SUBSCRIBE,this));
}

private void UnSubscribeNotification(){
    client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
    client.getPush().unsubscribe("myAndroid", new PushListener(PushListener.MODE_UNSUBSCRIBE,this));
}
```

Push Listener

```
public class PushListener implements WLOnReadyToSubscribeListener,WLResponseListener,WLEventSourceListener {

    public static final int MODE_CONNECT = 0;
    public static final int MODE_SUBSCRIBE = 1;
    public static final int MODE_UNSUBSCRIBE =2;

    private int mode ;
    private Context currentContext;

    public PushListener(int mode,Context ctx){
        this.mode = mode;
        currentContext = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyToSubscribe() {

        WLClient.getInstance().getPush().registerEventSourceCallback("myAndroid", "TaskAdapter","PushEventSource", this );

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(String arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {

        switch (mode){
            case MODE_CONNECT:
                // connect =true ;
                break;

            case MODE_SUBSCRIBE:
              TextView tt =  (TextView) (((Activity)currentContext).findViewById(R.id.tv_statusMsg));
                tt.setText("Subscribed");
                break;

            case MODE_UNSUBSCRIBE:
                // unsubscribe = true;
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
        switch (mode){
            case MODE_CONNECT:
                // connect =false ;
                break;

            case MODE_SUBSCRIBE:
                // subscribe = false;
                break;

            case MODE_UNSUBSCRIBE:
                //  unsubscribe = false;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Task Adapter

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'PushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest:'PushApplication-mobile-securityTest'


});

function deviceSubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){
    WL.Logger.debug(">> deviceSubscribeFunc");
}

function deviceUnsubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){
    WL.Logger.debug(">> deviceUnsubscribeFunc");
}



function submitNotification(userId, notificationText){

    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription==null){
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }

    var badgeDigit = 1;

    var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});



    notification.MPNS.raw = {
        payload : {payload : "You have a meeting in 5 minutes"}
    };

    WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);

    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);

    return { 
        result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId 
    };
}


function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;
    WL.Logger.debug("my test");
    return {
        authRequired: true,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){
   // if (username==="user" && password === "user"){

        var userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username,
                attributes: {
                    foo: "bar"
                }
        };

        WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);

        return {
            authRequired: false,
            user :userIdentity
        };
   // }

   // return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}


function getSecretData(){
    return {
        secretData: "A secret data to invoke authentication"
    };
}

function onLogout(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

AuthenticationConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
             US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->  

     <staticResources>
     <!--  
            <resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
        -->
        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>

    </staticResources> 


     <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true" isInternalDeviceID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>   

        <customSecurityTest name="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

        <mobileSecurityTest  name="PushApplication-mobile-securityTest">
          <testUser realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
          <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
       </mobileSecurityTest >

    </securityTests> 

    <realms>

    <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="SingleStepAuthRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="TaskAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="TaskAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>
        <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

        <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
        </realm>

    </realms>

    <loginModules>
        <loginModule name="AuthLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

LogCat Logs

```
04-29 16:38:21.997  20704-20704/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:38:41.417  20704-20711/com.vdot.pushdemo I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
04-29 16:39:42.957  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
04-29 16:39:42.957  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.vdot.pushdemo is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-29 16:39:42.967  21735-21741/com.vdot.pushdemo I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
04-29 16:39:43.167  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
04-29 16:39:43.167  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:43.367  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:43.567  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:43.567  21735-21741/com.vdot.pushdemo I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
04-29 16:39:43.777  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:43.977  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:44.167  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:44.367  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 16:39:44.577  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1321)
04-29 16:39:44.667  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/Activity﹕ #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
04-29 16:39:44.727  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.11
    Build Date: 09/12/14 Fri
    Local Branch: LA.3.6.1_20140912_070_patches
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
04-29 16:39:44.737  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/HWUI﹕ EGLImpl-HWUI Protected EGL context created
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ PartialUpdate status: Enabled
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Left Align: 8
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Width Align: 8
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Top Align: 1
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Height Align: 1
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Min ROI Width: 1
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Min ROI Height: 2
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Needs ROI Merge: 1
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Left Split=720
04-29 16:39:44.747  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/qdutils﹕ Right Split=720
04-29 16:39:44.757  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-29 16:40:03.527  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:40:04.077  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
04-29 16:40:04.077  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 529: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-29 16:40:04.077  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
04-29 16:40:04.087  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7327000 but found 7099030
04-29 16:40:04.097  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.common.Logger﹕ com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed once.
04-29 16:40:04.097  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices in GCMClientFactory.java:38 :: Failed to use Google Play Services becuase the return code is 2
04-29 16:40:04.107  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:28 :: Using GCMHelperClient
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setColor, referenced from method com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService.generateNotification
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 239: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setColor (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0039
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.visibility
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 31
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x59 at 0x0029
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.publicVersion
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x001b at 0x62 in Lcom/worklight/wlclient/push/GCMIntentService;.notify
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.category
04-29 16:40:04.117  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x000d at 0x72 in Lcom/worklight/wlclient/push/GCMIntentService;.notify
04-29 16:40:04.137  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:95 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:40:04.137  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:101 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:40:04.147  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:792 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@4370df08
04-29 16:40:04.197  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 16:40:04.227  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:40:04.237  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-25957(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
04-29 16:40:04.257  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-25957(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
04-29 16:40:04.257  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-25957(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-29 16:40:04.547  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-1 calls detatch()
04-29 16:40:06.777  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/invoke
04-29 16:40:06.977  21735-21760/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-2 calls detatch()
04-29 16:40:07.017  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:40:07.317  21735-21763/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-3 calls detatch()
04-29 16:40:07.387  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:40:07.817  21735-21765/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-4 calls detatch()
04-29 16:40:07.867  21735-21765/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-29 16:41:24.987  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:42:18.697  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:42:18.857  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/WLClient﹕ WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:213 :: WLClient has already been created.
04-29 16:42:18.877  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7327000 but found 7099030
04-29 16:42:18.897  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices in GCMClientFactory.java:38 :: Failed to use Google Play Services becuase the return code is 2
04-29 16:42:18.917  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:28 :: Using GCMHelperClient
04-29 16:42:18.937  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:95 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:42:18.967  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:101 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:42:18.997  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:792 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@439d5638
04-29 16:42:19.017  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:42:19.227  21735-21809/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-5 calls detatch()
04-29 16:42:19.277  21735-21809/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-29 16:42:22.257  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:42:22.427  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/WLClient﹕ WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:213 :: WLClient has already been created.
04-29 16:42:22.477  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:42:22.567  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/query
04-29 16:42:22.897  21735-21815/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-6 calls detatch()
04-29 16:42:22.927  21735-21815/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-29 16:42:23.007  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-1 calls detatch()
04-29 16:42:23.027  21735-21759/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-29 16:42:33.637  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-29 16:42:33.877  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/WLClient﹕ WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:213 :: WLClient has already been created.
04-29 16:42:33.897  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7327000 but found 7099030
04-29 16:42:33.917  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices in GCMClientFactory.java:38 :: Failed to use Google Play Services becuase the return code is 2
04-29 16:42:33.927  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:28 :: Using GCMHelperClient
04-29 16:42:33.957  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:95 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:42:33.987  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/GCMHelperClient﹕ GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java:101 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
04-29 16:42:34.007  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:792 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@43a4d3d0
04-29 16:42:34.037  21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-29 16:42:34.337  21735-21760/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-2 calls detatch()
04-29 16:42:34.367  21735-21760/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
```

Updated Log

```
04-30 09:22:38.027  30652-30652/com.vdot.pushdemo I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 09:22:38.037  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-30 09:22:38.047  30652-31059/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-26598(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
04-30 09:22:38.077  30652-31059/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-26598(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
04-30 09:22:38.077  30652-31059/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ Thread-26598(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-30 09:22:38.297  30652-31059/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-1 calls detatch()
04-30 09:22:40.617  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/invoke
04-30 09:22:40.737  30652-31064/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-2 calls detatch()
04-30 09:22:40.767  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-30 09:22:40.897  30652-31067/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-3 calls detatch()
04-30 09:22:40.947  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-30 09:22:41.197  30652-31069/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-4 calls detatch()
04-30 09:22:41.227  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateToken in WLPush.java:521 :: Registering at the GCM server.
04-30 09:22:41.237  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.clearSubscribedEventSources in WLPush.java:596 :: Clearing notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:22:41.247  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.clearSubscribedTags in WLPush.java:607 :: Clearing tag notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:22:41.257  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateSubscribedTags in WLPush.java:635 :: Updating tag notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:22:41.257  30652-31069/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-30 09:22:41.527  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMAPIClient﹕ GCMAPIClient$1.doInBackground in GCMAPIClient.java:45 :: Successfully registered with GCM using Google Play Services. Returned deviceToken:APA91bHvvCrMUQr-zI-CEjbmu3R7r7s_f9jPAMyBslPnQd16DPTveB96nzvYXRRIrzv_HbbMLdPitz-VjmhFKSZnFfC349IRSADxmfDm0h4ps82YUeTAGMUepUZhwrb7V24ExHLilp0qmcryQcn3pnmCOhPuJc6vZQ
04-30 09:22:41.537  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateTokenCallback in WLPush.java:756 :: Push notification device token has changed, Updating on server [serverToken: null, deviceToken: APA91bHvvCrMUQr-zI-CEjbmu3R7r7s_f9jPAMyBslPnQd16DPTveB96nzvYXRRIrzv_HbbMLdPitz-VjmhFKSZnFfC349IRSADxmfDm0h4ps82YUeTAGMUepUZhwrb7V24ExHLilp0qmcryQcn3pnmCOhPuJc6vZQ]
04-30 09:22:41.567  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/notifications
04-30 09:22:42.407  30652-31078/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-5 calls detatch()
04-30 09:22:49.337  30652-31078/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ onReadyToSubscribe
04-30 09:23:24.177  30652-30652/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-30 09:23:24.337  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/WLClient﹕ WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:213 :: WLClient has already been created.
04-30 09:23:24.377  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:25 :: Using GCMAPIClient
04-30 09:23:24.397  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:792 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@439f2148
04-30 09:23:24.427  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/wl.request﹕ WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://10.136.78.232:10080/MFPushDemo/apps/services/api/AndroidPushDemo/Androidnative/init
04-30 09:23:24.617  30652-31085/com.vdot.pushdemo I/System.out﹕ pool-3-thread-6 calls detatch()
04-30 09:23:24.657  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateToken in WLPush.java:521 :: Registering at the GCM server.
04-30 09:23:24.677  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.clearSubscribedEventSources in WLPush.java:596 :: Clearing notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:23:24.687  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateSubscribedEventSources in WLPush.java:614 :: Updating notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:23:24.697  30652-31085/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ Mode Connect Success
04-30 09:23:24.697  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.clearSubscribedTags in WLPush.java:607 :: Clearing tag notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:23:24.707  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.updateSubscribedTags in WLPush.java:635 :: Updating tag notification subscriptions.
04-30 09:23:24.807  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMAPIClient﹕ GCMAPIClient$1.doInBackground in GCMAPIClient.java:45 :: Successfully registered with GCM using Google Play Services. Returned deviceToken:APA91bHvvCrMUQr-zI-CEjbmu3R7r7s_f9jPAMyBslPnQd16DPTveB96nzvYXRRIrzv_HbbMLdPitz-VjmhFKSZnFfC349IRSADxmfDm0h4ps82YUeTAGMUepUZhwrb7V24ExHLilp0qmcryQcn3pnmCOhPuJc6vZQ
04-30 09:23:24.817  30652-31086/com.vdot.pushdemo D/com.demo.push﹕ onReadyToSubscribe
04-30 09:24:08.677  30652-30652/com.vdot.pushdemo D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-30 09:24:08.877  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/WLClient﹕ WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:213 :: WLClient has already been created.
04-30 09:24:08.917  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕ GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:25 :: Using GCMAPIClient
04-30 09:24:08.927  30652-31058/com.vdot.pushdemo W/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush﹕ WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:792 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@43a356a0
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Because you say that you already login to the app, try w/out the securityTest on the event source. It's not required. Also, add LogCat logs from the time the app is launched, perhaps this is GCM configuration-related.

Comment: Removed the security Test, but still no luck. Yesterday an IBM employee has done remote on to my machine but still unable to figure out the issue.
I was told from IBM  to create a brand new application for push  instead of using existing app and see if it is working or not .

Comment: What about the LogCat logs?

Comment: Hi Idan, created a brand new application and posted logcat logs..
Interesting thing is for the first time onReadyToSubscribe has fired and i saw the the application on the application tab on console, after some time it stopped working again. I tried disabling my antivirus too..

Answer (score 0):

From the LogCat logs it appears you are using an outdated Google Play Services:

> 04-29 16:42:33.897  21735-21735/com.vdot.pushdemo
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   7327000 but found 7099030 04-29 16:42:33.917 
>   21735-21758/com.vdot.pushdemo D/GCMClientFactory﹕
>   GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices in GCMClientFactory.java:38 ::
>   Failed to use Google Play Services because the return code is 2

Push notifications require Google Play Services. If this service fails to initialize, push may indeed not work.

Open the Android SDK Manager, update the Play Services components and make sure the application is properly configured to use it. Then try again.

Comment: Hi Idan, Updated by Google play service from SDK. After update I went to  Android\android sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
and checked the version number i have. I have 7.3.0 as latest, but when i put 7.3.0 in build.gradle it is asking me to update the google play service on the device. I don't have authorization for this device to update, so i went ahead and changed the version number to 7.0.0. Registration has been successful but getting a message like  Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server".Posted updated log too.